# Rendered view is not displaying in my back office in PS 1.7

Tags: php, module, twig, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to create a view in the back office tab that I created in the installation of my Module. My Module adds the tab like this:

```
protected function _installTabs()
{
    if(!$tabId = \Tab::getIdFromClassName('IezonPortfolio')) {
        $tab = new \Tab();
        $tab->class_name = 'IezonPortfolio';
        $tab->module = $this->name;
        $tab->id_parent = \Tab::getIdFromClassName('ShopParameters');
        $tab->active = 1;
        
        foreach (Language::getLanguages(false) as $lang):               
           $tab->name[(int) $lang['id_lang']] = 'My Portfolio';
        endforeach;
        
        return $tab->save();
    }
    
   new \Tab((int) $tabId);
   return true;
}
```

This works fine and I can navigate to my Shop Parameters and click the My Portfolio tab. The issue I'm having is that it is blank. My ModuleAdminController looks like this:

```
class IezonPortfolioController extends ModuleAdminController {
    private $_module;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_module = \Module::getInstanceByName('iezonportfolio');
    }
    
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('@Modules/iezonportfolio/views/templates/admin/display.html.twig', array(
            'contents_iezonportfolio' => $this->_module->selectAll()
        ));
    }
}
```

My display.html.twig just has `test` in it to see if it would output anything which it didn't. [On looking at the Docs](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/) it doesn't mention anything other than using the `render` function and returning it. Any help would be appreciated. I just get a blank Tab.

EDIT: After looking at some of the pre-installed modules and referencing them to the Docs, I saw that I was missing my route configuration. My Controller is in the documented directory set-up: `iezonportfolio/controllers/admin/iezonportfolio.php` so I made my route like this:

```
iezonportfolio:
  path: iezonportfolio
  methods: [GET]
  defaults:
    _controller: 'IezonPortfolio\Controllers\Admin\Controller::indexAction'
    _legacy_controller: 'IezonPortfolioController'
    _legacy_link: 'IezonPortfolioController:index'
```

This has still not yet fixed the blank display so I tried to dig deeper into some other modules and have now updated my display.html.twig to show this:

```
{% extends '@PrestaShop/Admin/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
  Test
{% endblock %}
```

This did not fix the blank display either. I hope this addition is useful for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the modern controllers works, you are extending legacy `ModuleAdminController`, take a look here:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/example-modules

you have a plenty of module examples, here's a little snippet from one of those modules:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PrestaShop\Module\DemoControllerTabs\Controller\Admin;

use PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MinimalistController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController
{
    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('@Modules/democontrollertabs/views/templates/admin/minimalist.html.twig');
    }
}
```

I recommend you to think wether you want to use, or not, modern controller. It depends on wether you want to sell your module, use it in client projects etc.

Comment: I'm lost, the documentation states to build a Tab in the back office, you need a `ModuleAdminController` which works perfectly fine, the issue then is, the `indexAction` is not being executed even though I have a route to do so, I don't think its got anything to do with that... also, the example you've given is using PRS-4 which I don't want, this isn't for sale, this is to extend a prestashop site but at this rate, I might just build it from scratch cos this is stupidly difficult to just create a view

Comment: there's literally none informations about `ModuleAdminController` here: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/

you're mixing two versions of admin controllers into one ;)

Comment: to explain it more clearly:

- PrestaShop 1.6 is not using Twig nor Symfony, and legacy controllers are created by extending `ModuleAdminController`
- PrestaShop 1.7 is using Symfony and Twig and you can create "modern controllers", you have everything explained in documentation and few example modules in official repository

Comment: I get this error `UndefinedMethodException` if I change it to a `FrameworkBundleAdminController`. on Line `$controller->run()`

Comment: `Attempted to call an undefined method named "run" of class "IezonPortfolioController".`